# How to scale to thousands of producer-consumer pairs in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a usecase where I want to have thousands of producers writing messages which will be consumed by thousands of corresponding consumers. Each producer's message is meant for exactly one consumer.

Going through the core concepts [here](https://medium.com/inspiredbrilliance/kafka-basics-and-core-concepts-5fd7a68c3193) and [here](https://medium.com/inspiredbrilliance/kafka-basics-and-core-concepts-5fd7a68c3193): it seems like each consumer-producer pair should have its own topic. Is this correct understanding? I also looked into consumer groups but it seems they are more for parallellizing consumption.

Right now I have multiple producer-consumer pairs sharing very few topics, but because of that (i think) I am having to read a lot of messages in the consumer and filter them out for the specific producer's messages by the key. As my system scales this might take a lot of time. Also in the event I have to delete the checkpoint this will be even more problematic as it starts reading from the very beginning.

Is creating thousands of topics the solution for this? Or is there any other way to use concepts like partitions, consumer groups etc? Both producers and consumers are spark streaming/batch applications. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Each producer's message is meant for exactly one consumer

Assuming you commit the offsets, and don't allow retries, this is the expected behavior of all Kafka consumers (or rather, *consumer groups*)

> seems like each consumer-producer pair should have its own topic

Not really. As you said, you have many-to-many relationship of clients. You do not need to have a known pair ahead of time; a producer could send data with no expected consumer, then any consumer application(s) in the future should be able to subscribe to that topic for the data they are interested in.

> sharing very few topics, but because of that (i think) I am having to read a lot of messages in the consumer and filter them out for the specific producer's messages by the key. As my system scales this might take a lot of time

The consumption would take linearly more time on a higher production rate, yes, and partitions are the way to solve for that. Beyond that, you need faster network and processing. You still need to consume and deserialize in order to filter, so the filter is not the bottleneck here.

> Is creating thousands of topics the solution for this?

Ultimately depends on your data, but I'm guessing not.

Comment: "The consumption would take linearly more time on a higher production rate" - the problem is, if I have a 1000 producers writing to the same topic, then one consumer needs to read the entire topic (last 7 days) and then filter down to its specific messages. so that makes filtering the bottleneck, isnt it? ( If there is a checkpoint (spark streaming) i understand it will read only from that offset, but if a new consumer is introduced, it has to start from the beginning of the topic)

Comment: Number of producers doesn't matter; it's the rate at which they produce. And unclear how that is a bottleneck unless the filter needs to use an external long-running process since equality checks/conditionals would be O(1) constant-time, and consuming alone is O(n) linear time.

Answer (score 0):

> Is creating thousands of topics the solution for this? Or is there any
> other way to use concepts like partitions, consumer groups etc? Both
> producers and consumers are spark streaming/batch applications.

What's the reason you want to have thousands of consumers? or want to have a 1 to 1 explicit relationship? As mentioned earlier, only one consumer within a consumer group will process a message. This is normal.

If however you are trying to make your record processing extremely concurrent, instead of using very high partition counts or very large consumer groups, should use something like [Parallel Consumer](https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer) (PC).

By using PC, you can processing all your keys in parallel, regardless of how long it takes to process, and you can be as concurrent as you wish .

PC directly solves for this, by sub partitioning the input partitions by key and processing each key in parallel.
It also tracks per record acknowledgement. Check out [Parallel Consumer on GitHub](https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer) (it's open source BTW, and I'm the author).